# Can I modify JSON inside javascript tag thats added to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a piece of code that I drop in on the page using server side code. We also have a CDN in front of the site so more than likely the page will be picked from cache rather than server so when the page renders I want to check if the user is logged in, if he is then I would like to take some info from the cookie and encrypt it on the page. This json data will be used by a third party.

```
    dmpLayer = [
                  "title":"Some random text",
                   "userid": ""
               ]
```

Above code becomes/or should become like this

```
    dmpLayer = [
                  "title":"Some random text",
                   "userid": sha256value("some user info")
               ]
```

How would I accomplish this using javascript?

Comment: Note that what you have isn't JSON. It's also not valid as you're got properties within an array. Presumably you want an object instead

Comment: You should use the CDN to cache stuff that doesn't change, not stuff that does (especially when it changes on an individual user basis).  Looks like you need to rethink your caching strategy a little - the correct place for doing this is to just render a different output on your server.

Comment: Yes you can. However, if a third party will fetch this data using a webrequest, the data will not change as this does not execute javascript.

Comment: you just need to change the text or the whole object of dmplayer?